# yajrabox datatable translation

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

I'm using yajrabox datatable and I'm having this problem when I'm trying to use localization on titles.

```
protected $exportColumns = [
    'name'       => ['data' => 'name', 'name' => 'name',           'title' => trans('datatable.classroomDatatable.classroom'), 'className' => "text-center", 'printable' => true, 'exportable' => true],
    'course'     => ['data' => 'course', 'name' => 'course',       'title' => trans('datatable.classroomDatatable.branch'), 'className' => "text-center", 'printable' => true, 'exportable' => true],
    'caretaker'  => ['data' => 'caretaker', 'name' => 'caretaker', 'title' => trans('datatable.classroomDatatable.caretaker'), 'className' => "text-center", 'printable' => true, 'exportable' => true, ]
    
];
```

Error:

> Constant expression contains invalid operations

What I'm doing wrong on this?
Thanks in advance